# How to use Reorderable with Sqflite list?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I am saving a list of profiles in sqflite and I am trying to make my list reorderable. In my Helper class I have these methods:

```
 static Future insertProfile(Map<String, dynamic> profile) async {
    await db.insert('Profiles', profile);
  }

  static Future deleteProfile(int id) async {
    await db.delete('Profiles', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  static Future updateProfile(Map<String, dynamic> profile) async {
    await db.update('Profiles', profile,
        where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [profile['id']]);
  }
```

My profiles list looks like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Profiles')),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: ProfileProvider.getProfileList(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            var profiles = snapshot.data;
            return snapshot.data == null
                ? Container()
                : ReorderableListView(
                    children: List.generate(
                      profiles.length,
                      (index) {
                        return Dismissible(
                          key: ValueKey("value$index"),
                          background: slideBackground(),
                          onDismissed: (direction) {
                            ProfileProvider.deleteProfile(
                                profiles[index]['id']);
                            showSnackBar(
                                context, profiles[index]['title'], [index]);
                          },
```

I am trying to replicate this type of function, but with Sqlite:

```
void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
  setState(
    () {
      if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
        newIndex -= 1;
      }
      final String item = profiles.removeAt(oldIndex);
      profiles.insert(newIndex, item);
    },
  );
}
```

So far I have managed deleting successfully:

```
onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                      if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
                        newIndex -= 1;
                      }
                      setState(
                        () {
                          ProfileProvider.deleteProfile(profiles[oldIndex]['id']);
                        },
                      );
                    },
```

The problem is I can't find how to reinsert the same profile at the new index.

I tried many things but the latest is this:

```
                          var item = profiles[oldId]['id'];
                          ProfileProvider.deleteProfile(profiles[oldId]['id']);
                          ProfileProvider.insertProfile(item);
```

However, I get this error message :

```
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `insertProfile` expects a Map, but you oass an int.
Also as a tip: give your Future an additional type parameter, what kind of type they eventually return. Makes type errors easier to spot.